# if condition for String

Tags: java

I wanna ask you , 
do you have a solution for this question (`if` statement) or where is the error ?

```
String z = input.nextLine() ;  //i want from the user value of z  .
if (z ==( "Y" || "y" )) 
{  
    statement ... 
}     
else if (z==("N" || "n" ))    
{  
    statement ... 
}
```

How to write a condition for `if` when the condition of String in Java  ?

Comment: use equals to compare strings!

Answer (score 2):

you can say

```
if(z.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
    //code...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for [`equalsIgnoreCase`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29). You can use it like

```
if (z.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")){//do your job
```

Answer (score 1):

use `equals().`

`==` does reference equality which you don't want.

So use `equals()` as you want to check the content equality.